# FileNotFoundException for HttpURLConnection in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

I have an Android app that works fine with Android 2.x and 3.x, but it fails when run on Android 4.x.

The problem is in this section of code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://blahblah.blah/somedata.xml");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();

InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

When the application is running on Android 4.x, the `getInputStream()` call results in a `FileNotFoundException`. When the same binary is running on earlier versions of Android, it succeeds. The URLs also work fine in web browsers and with `curl`.

Apparently something about `HttpURLConnection` has changed in ICS. Does anybody have any idea what has changed, and/or what the fix might be?

Comment: The docs say that `setDoOutput(true)` implies `setRequestMethod("POST")`. Which do you mean?

Comment: It's meant to do a GET. (I didn't write the code, so I don't know why `setDoOutput(true)` was there.)

Comment: FWIW, `setRequestMethod("GET")` and `setDoOutput(true)` appear in a lot of sample code for using `HttpURLConnection`. Where is it documented that it forces a POST?

Comment: **HTTP Methods**

`HttpURLConnection` uses the `GET` method by default. It will use `POST` if `setDoOutput(true)` has been called. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: it's quite old, but what i did is just i ommited the conn.setRequestMethod("GET") , 
we set the conn.setDoOutput(true) which means it's a POST and vis versa

Comment: from docs: setDoOutput(true) :Sets the flag indicating whether this {@code URLConnection} allows output. It cannot be set after the connection is established.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try removing the setDoOutput call.  Taken from this blog:
[a blog](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/195330)

Edit: This is needed when using a POST call.

Comment: Yeah, sure enough, removing that line makes it work on ICS, and it seems to still work on older Android as well.

Comment: Note that this is needed, when making a POST request! In that case, it should be kept in place.

Comment: Hey guys. What do you do when you are using a POST call?

Answer (score 30):

A FileNotFoundException may also been thrown if the server returns a bad error code (e.g., 400 or 401). You can handle this as follows:

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode(); //can call this instead of con.connect()
if (responseCode >= 400 && responseCode <= 499) {
    throw new Exception("Bad authentication status: " + responseCode); //provide a more meaningful exception message
}
else {
    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: I was getting response code 500, because I hadn't set `Content-Type`, thanks for pointing out that this exception might be thrown in those cases.

Comment: For anyone wondering why they don't have the "getResponseCode()" method: just cast your connection to a HttpURLConnection

Comment: Does anyone know *why* Android throws a FileNotFoundException on codes [which clearly aren't 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)?

Comment: @DavidLord I had this error because my URL wasn't properly formatted. I used `URLEncoder.encode(myURL, "UTF-8");` for the part of my URL that contained a space character, and it all went well.

Answer (score 6):

I Don't know why, but dealing manually with redirection resolves the problem.

```
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

Comment: In my situation, I was using an Authorization header to load a script on my website, which redirects to a pre-signed URL on Digital Ocean Spaces (S3 compatible). Android was also sending the Authorization header with the redirected request and that was causing Spaces to return a 400 error. This is on Android 5; later versions don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but you can also verify the accepted content. You can add this line to accept all kinds of contents

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
```