# I can't load open weather map icons

Tags: android

I am working with this 
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html
tutorial to learn how use weather services in my app. I run this tutorial and it works fine. But I've got one problem. Can't load icons. Logcat error is

java.io.FileNotFoundExeption:
 http://openweathermap.org/img/w/ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionTmpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnctionTmpl.java:186)

When I open this link in Chrome I can see the image so I don't know why it can't be found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: code is there 
https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/tree/master/WeatherApp Error in line 87 of file "WeatherHttpClient.java"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same error, you must remove:

```
con.setDoOutput(true);
```

because is forcing a POST instead of a GET on the connection, more info on:

[FileNotFoundException for HttpURLConnection in Ice Cream Sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365829/filenotfoundexception-for-httpurlconnection-in-ice-cream-sandwich)

Answer (score 3):

add .png file extension

String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
 private static String IMG_URL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/";

con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(IMG_URL + code +".png")).openConnection();