# Clojure Android HTTP request

Tags: java, android, clojure

How do I go about making an HTTP request in a [Clojure Android](http://clojure-android.info/) project?

- neither `clj-http` nor `http-kit` seem to be Android-friendly
- the approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389317/how-to-http-request-clojure-on-android-lein-droid-neko) gives a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Attempting to resolve that `Exception` according to the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650921/quick-fix-for-networkonmainthreadexception) has various problems. The preferred solution (using `AsyncTask`) requires subclassing, and I'm not entirely clear how to write Clojure code that does so. Trying to change `StrictMode` settings results in namespace-related errors. Finally, starting up a new thread to handle the web request with `(.start (Thread. (fn [] ...)))` crashes out the app entirely in testing.

So, once more: how do I go about making an HTTP request in an Android application written using Clojure Android?

Comment: you could try to use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which is said work nice on android. Here's a simple example: https://github.com/bamboo/clojure-retrofit-spike

Comment: @leetwinski - no dice, looks like :/ Merely `import`ing `[retrofit.http GET Path]` causes the project to crash on-device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [the question you linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389317/how-to-http-request-clojure-on-android-lein-droid-neko), their (maslurp) works in the android [Clojure REPL app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sattvik.clojure_repl), if (.setDoOutput) is set to false instead, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366532/385667), AND you wrap the call in a [`future`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) (to avoid the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`) :

```
(defn maslurp [url]
  (let [a (new java.io.BufferedReader
               (new java.io.InputStreamReader
                    (.getInputStream (doto (.openConnection (new java.net.URL url))
                                       (.setRequestMethod "GET")
                                       (.setDoOutput false) ; false for GET
                                       (.setUseCaches false)))))]
    (loop [r (.readLine a) s ""]
      (if (nil? r)
        s
        (recur (.readLine a) (clojure.string/join [s r]))))))


@(future (maslurp "https://www.google.com"))
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem. The question is about running HTTP requests in an app built with [Clojure Android](http://clojure-android.info/) (added link to question to clarify). In that context, calling the above definition still raises an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: There is the clojure-android neko library, which includes support for calling `(future (let [..] (on-ui (..)))`: [https://github.com/clojure-android/neko/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=on-ui]